# Difference between state function and eigenfunction

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Is there any difference when we say in quantum mechanics the *eigenfunction* of an operator and the *state function*? Can we use the two terms as supplementary to one another?

Comment: People, if you are going to down-vote a new user, give a reason.

Comment: Operators act on states. An eigenfunction of an operator is a specific state that is natural to the operator. I haven't heard of the notion of a state function - do you mean by this a function of a state?

Comment: The relationship is easier to see if you think of an eigenfunction as an eigenstate. So eigenstates are a subset of states.

Comment: yes I mean function of a state. Thank you for the correction

Comment: I think a state function of a physical system is a combination of various eigenfunctions belonging to different operators describing the state with a particular eigenvalue..as the state function is a combined description e.g.different angular momentum ,spin..etc are part of a state function.

Comment: That means a state function is the set of all eigenfunction of different operators. Am I right?